# Child, Parent and Grand-Parent relationship where a child may not necessary have a parent or a grand parent

Tags: mysql, database-design

Here, I have some problem representing a hostel-room-inmate entities.

First an inmate is given a hostel seat,

Then he is allotted a particular hostel,

Then he is allotted a room.

My approach is that the inmate table contains a parent-link to the room table, the room table contains a parent-link to the hostel table.

```
table hostel(id, name)
table room(id, hostel_id, room_no)
table inmate(id, room_id, name, etc)
```

But while at the stage of allotment, the inmate is first allotted a hostel, in which the room_id is to be left blank, thereby meaning that the inmate is not allotted a hostel room and so on...

How do I solve this problem please...

I wanted to use it in Laravel development environment

(NB: I have some idea of creating many-to-many relationship type by creating relationship table, but just asking if there's better approach than this.)

Comment: I do not see the problem. Your scheme does not describe the process. It describes states: initial (inmate is not allotted) and final (inmate is allotted a room in a hostel). That's all. Your reasoning about displaying the intermediate state doesn't make sense.

Comment: Sounds like you need both hostel_id and room_id on inmate - which accommodates both allocated to a hostel and allocated to a particual room (within a hostel).

Answer (score 1):

I would add hostel_id to inmate, and leave Room-id empty till he arrives and the room-number is chosen.

So you could also, allow inmate to book a specific room with sea view for example

And you could check if any rooms for a date are available, for example hostel 1 has 10 room and 10 users have chosen the hostel already, you ca tell him  that is not possible and give additional information when a room is free again or a hostel nearby who has vacancy.

```
table hostel(id, name)
table inmate(id,hostel_id, room_id, name, etc)
table room(id, hostel_id, room_no)
```